# Restricting window.find to a textarea

Tags: javascript

Right now clicking on a function name in the yellow box highlights it first then clicking again scrolls the textarea. How do I just scroll the textarea?

```
$('.codepointer').live('click', function() {
    window.find($(this).text());
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

[image]